# App State Changes when changing language within the android app

Tags: android, localization, sharedpreferences, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-context

We are using a total of 6 languages inside our android app, which user can choose from. We are setting the locale programmatically. The languages are 
English, Hindi, Tamil, Telegu, Kannada, Malayalam, Marathi.

Using the code below we change the app's language.

```
locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
conf.locale = locale;

getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

When we change the language between Hindi and English app is able to get the data from shared preferences, but for the other languages, it returns null for the same query. Please help

Update 1 : Following is the code to retrieve data from shared preference

```
  SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shared_prefs_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  String value = sharedPrefs.getString(key, null);
```

Comment: `it returns null for the same query.` show work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using string value to get the data from sharedpreferences `R.string.shared_prefs_key` that is why the issues is occurring because the key would be changing in different language string. And since the data was stored during different key, it gives null for other language keys.

Change that to a constant value like below:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("<your key>", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```